# Format results in Bash

Tags: bash, sed

For example, I have **test.txt** with the following line:

> L1~00~00~00~00~00~Test~122113~00~L2~This~Is~A~Sample~Data~L1~00~00~00~00~00~Test1~123456~00

I want to get "**Test**" and "**Test1**", both are after `L1~00~00~00~00~00~` with the following format.

```
Test, Test1
```

I already have this line in my bash script:

```
grep -oP 'L1(?:.[\w\s]*){5}.(\K[\w\s]*)' < test.txt
```

But it returns a different format:

```
Test
Test1
```

How can I achieve this by adding `sed` in my script? I'm still a newbie. I hope somebody could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, if you are using Perl regex anyway, you might as well use Perl directly.

```
perl -nle '@m = m/L1(?:.[\w\s]*){5}.([\w\s]*)/g; print(join(",", @m)) if @m' test.txt
```

This collects matches into `@m`, then prints them joined by a comma if there are matches in `@m`.  The `-l` option is a convenience to supply the trailing newline on the `print`, and the `-n` option makes Perl loop over the input lines one at a time, like `sed`.

Comment: Is it okay if I'll use it in bash? I'm not really sure of what I'm doing, I'm sorry. But I can just convert everything to perl. Does it have any difference?

Comment: `perl` is a shell command just like `grep` or `sed`.  You can convert the entire process to a Perl script if you like, of course, but that's clearly outside the scope of this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
grep -oP 'L1(?:.[\w\s]*){5}.(\K[\w\s]*)' test.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/, /'
Test, Test1
```

Comment: I'll try this one. :)

Comment: It works with two results only. But what if I have more than 2? Anyway I'll just revise this one. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can use: `grep -oP 'L1(?:.[\w\s]*){5}.(\K[\w\s]*)' test.txt | awk -v ORS=', ' '1' | sed 's/, $/\n/'`

Comment: @User122113 You could use `sed -n ':;$!{N;b};$s/\n/, /gp'` to repeat the the line joining.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not inclined using `perl` regex - you can cling to `sed` alone:

```
sed -rn 's#(L1.)((\w+.){5})(\w+)(.*\1\2)(\w+)(.*)#\4, \6#p' < test.txt
```

Comment: Can use `sed -r 's/L1/\nL1/g;s/L1(.[\w]*){5}.([\w]*)[^\n]*\n?/\2, /g'` if there are more than two

Comment: The Perl 5 escape sequences `\w` and `\s` are not universally available in `sed`, though some `sed` dialects support them.  Similarly, `\n` will work to match a newline in some `sed` versions, but not in others.

Answer (score 1):

Wth GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='L1~00~00~00~00~00~' -F~ 'NF{ORS=(RT?", ":"\n"); print $1}' file
Test, Test1
```

The above just splits each line into records that contain whatever is between `L1~00~00~00~00~00~`s, and splits each record into fields between `~`s and then prints the first field of each (which is the text that comes between each `L1~00~00~00~00~00~` and the next `~`) followed by `,` if it's not the last record and `\n` if it is.